# error when trying to connect to windows computer with Remmina

Tags: windows, 22.04, remmina

I have ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to connect to a local windows computer with Remmina. I can connect to this same windows computer from another windows computer using remote desktop. When I try to connect with Remmina I get these errors:

```
This window can help you find connection problems.
You can stop and start the logging at any moment using the On/Off switch.
The stats button (Ctrl+T), can be useful to gather system info you may share when reporting a bug.
There is more info about debugging Remmina on https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging
(DEBUG) - (rcw_map_event) - Mapping: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_map_event) - Calling plugin mapping function
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Opening connection
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Disable smooth scrolling is set to 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Adding GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Have SSH
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - RDP data path is /home/xyz/.local/share/remmina/RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Not using system proxy settings
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel init
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - SSH tunnel initialization…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port (tunnel)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - server: 10.0.0.5, port: 3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - protocol_plugin_start_direct_tunnel() returned [10.0.0.5]:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel has been optionally initialized. Now connecting to 10.0.0.5:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - gfx_h264_available: 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set by the user: 596x440
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set after workarounds: 596x440
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_type: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_username: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_hostname: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_port: 80
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Log level set to to INFO
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “password” deleted for file /home/xyz/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xyz_10-0-0-5.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_password” deleted for file /home/xyz/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xyz_10-0-0-5.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/xyz/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xyz_10-0-0-5.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/xyz/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_xyz_10-0-0-5.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Could not disconnect
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remmina uses xfreerdp which uses openssl to encrypt the connection via RDP to a windows computer.

Ubuntu 22.04 shipped with OpenSSL 3.0. Openssl3 changed the default security level of tls<1.2 and sha1 to from security level 1 to 0. This means that Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 (maybe 2012 too?) and older will not work by default.

If you want a quick test before trying to get a new version of Remmina, just run freerdp from the terminal with TLS downgraded:

`xfreerdp /v:hostname_or_ip /u:username /p:password /cert:ignore /tls-seclevel:0`

Ubuntu 22.04 has Remmina 1.4.25 as its latest version, but this issue was [fixed in Remmina 1.4.26](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/7839) and as of 2022-07-21 Remmina is currently at version 1.4.27.

There is some discussion to backport remmina 1.4.26 to Ubuntu 22.04, but until that happens you can install the flatpack, snap, or recompiled version. There is a PPA for Remmina and it is at version 1.4.27 so all is well, but it isn't maintained on a regular basis and can be a month or two behind.

Once you have the latest version, right click on your saved RDP connection and select "edit". Under the "Advanced" tab, change the "TLS Security Level" from default to "0 - Windows 7 compatible". Then click the "Save and Connect" button.

[Remmina has an excellent guide to update to the latest version.](https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/)
Due note that flatpak and snap don't work too well with themes, so if aesthetics are important to you, install the package for your OS instead.