# Can't connect to remote server using Remmina

Tags: remmina

I used Remmina for extablishing an RDP connection to a remote server for which I have credentials. I used it until a few months ago and worked smoothly. Today I tried connecting to that same server again and I get the error "Cannot connect to the  server"
I don't know why I get this error. When I first tried to connect to the server I got no errors so I didn't have to change any setting so I don't know if any setting was mistakenly changed.
Anyone knows what I can do for solving this problem?

EDIT:
My Ubuntu version is 22.04, the Remmina version is 1.4.25
I turned on debugging mode. This is the log. I'm sorry if I drop the whole log but I really don't know where's the problem. Maybe it is the rco_on_disconnect signal?

```
(DEBUG) - (rcw_map_event) - Mapping: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_map_event) - Calling plugin 
mapping function
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Opening connection
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Disable smooth scrolling is set to 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Adding GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Have SSH
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - RDP data path is /home/francesco/.local/share/remmina/RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Not using system proxy settings
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel init
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - SSH tunnel initialization…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port (tunnel)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - server: IP, port: PORT
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - protocol_plugin_start_direct_tunnel() returned [IP]:PORT
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel has been optionally initialized. Now connecting to IP:PORT
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - gfx_h264_available: 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set by the user: 592x440
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set after workarounds: 592x440
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_type: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_username: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_hostname: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_port: 80
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Network settings not set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list: 
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Log level set to to INFO
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “password” saved for file /home/francesco/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_tesi_IP-PORT.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_password” deleted for file /home/francesco/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_tesi_IP-PORT.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/francesco/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_tesi_IP-PORT.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/francesco/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_tesi_IP-PORT.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Could not disconnect
```

Comment: I suppose you need another client to test and rule out the possibility that something has changed on the server.  Or, maybe whoever looks after the network(s) in between haven't suddenly added a firewall between you and that server.

Comment: Great to have you join the community. Can you please add some details about your Ubuntu client (e.g. release)? As well, Remmina also offers a debug option. Output from that would be helpful. I mention that, in part, because Ubuntu clients have (obviously) changed over the years, and Remmina has expectations about connectivity.

Comment: @Ray I looked for public RDP servers for checking that aspect but I couldn't find any. Do you know if there exists a public RDP server?

Comment: @richbl thank you for the suggestions, I edited my post accordingly

Comment: @Frank. Thanks for the debug output. Please review one possible solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1419793/32664. This resolved my issue (similar in some respects to your current issue).

Comment: @Frank, was this issue resolved? If so, please indicate as much so others might benefit from your issue and resolution. Thanks

Comment: @richbl I solved the issue but I don't know how. I tried multiple times to connect and it eventually worked but I didn't make any changes